# Curious behavior of String()

Tags: javascript

I was just messing around with some code today, and I noticed that when I run `String(null)` or `String(undefined)`, I get `null` and `undefined` respectively. But, when I checked the value I got for `String([null, undefined])`, I found it gave me `","` as compared to the expected Result `null,undefined`. Does anyone have any idea on why this is happening? Since I didn't expect such behavior from `String` constructor on arrays, because as far as I have Noticed, the constructor simply put the values of every single one of the elements separated by commas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`String(x)` calls `x.toString()`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/text-processing.html#sec-string-constructor-string-value).

`null` and `undefined` values are represented by empty strings by [Arrays' `toString()`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.tostring) since it calls [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.join) ("If element is undefined or null, let next be the empty String"):

```
> [null, undefined].toString()
","
> [null, null, null, null].toString()
",,,"
```

Comment: Ah, understood. That means that `<Array>.toString` does not work in the way I perceived it did. Thanks for the clarification! I'll accept this answer when my timer ends, which is in 11 minutes

Comment: This is actually an artifact of the `Array#toString()` method calling `join()` which coerces `undefined`, `null`, and empty array `[]` to empty strings. see: [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#description) or the [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.tostring)

Comment: @pilchard Thanks, I folded that into the answer too!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
String([null, undefined].map(String));
```

or

```
[null, undefined].map(String).join()
```