# Why do arrays coerce in a specific way?

Tags: javascript, coercion

I'm struggling to understand why this examples below end up with this kind of results.

```
String([,,,]); // ',,' why?


Number([8,8]); // NaN    why?
```

please explain with details if possible

Comment: Why are you even trying to do this with arrays?

Comment: Cause numbers separate the decimals with . and not with , that is used to join arrays to a string.

Comment: In the first case, trailing commas are ignored when creating an array. Hence 2 commas instead of 3.

Comment: @pilchard weird, the previous question seems to overlap with this one: [Curious behavior of String()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68377293). I can only assume there is a course that is giving out these bizarre tasks, it just boggles my mind *why*.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `String` calls the `toString` method on the object, which, for arrays, is equivalent to calling `Array#join`.

```
String([,,,]);
```

`[,,,]` is an array with 3 empty elements. `[,,,].join()` will then put two commas as separators between the empty elements, resulting in `",,"`.

```
Number([8,8]);
```

`[8,8].join()` returns `"8,8"`, which cannot be parsed as a `Number`, so it produces `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I don't have enough reputation to vote unfortunately.  It's my first day here.

Comment: @Shaqe No problem.

Comment: @Shaqe If this answers your question, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.